# Add Object To Beginning of Array

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a tableView and an array that contains data to populate each cell. I then have a button to a new view controller to write a post and then add it to the beginning of the tableView array in the unwindSegue.

```
postObject *person = [[postObject alloc]initWithName:@"Peter Parker" Event:@"Birthday " Post:@"It's gonna be nuts!!!!" Image:nil profileImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"guy1.jpeg"]];
postObject *person2 = [[postObject alloc]initWithName:@"Jackie Miller" Event:nil Post:nil Image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone.png"] profileImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"girl1.jpeg"]];
postObject *person3 = [[postObject alloc]initWithName:@"Johnny" Event:@"Gay fest" Post:@"This app sucks" Image:nil profileImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"guy2.jpeg"]];
postObject *person4 = [[postObject alloc]initWithName:@"Hailey Walker" Event:@ Beach Fest" Post:@"Hey Guys!!!" Image:nil profileImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"girl2.jpeg"]];
self.postArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:person, person2, person3, person4, nil];
```

The next Page then adds the post to the array:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"newPost"]) {
    NSLog(@"Called");
    postObject *newPost = [[postObject alloc]initWithName:@"Johnny Boy" Event:@"Vegas" Post:@"It works!!"  Image:nil profileImage:nil];
    storyboardController *nextPage = segue.destinationViewController;
    [nextPage.postArray insertObject:newPost atIndex:0];
 }
 }
```

I call [tableView reloadData] in the unwindSegue but the tableview is all out of whack. The posts overlap with each other and some text doesn't display. If I simply add the object to the end of the array it works but not when I add it to the beginning.   Heres my cell for row at index path:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
postObject *currentPost = [self.postArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
self.cell = (storyboardCell *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if (currentPost.imagePost == nil) {
    _cell.personStringPost.text = currentPost.postString;
    _cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
if (currentPost.imagePost != nil) {
    _cell.personImagePost.image = currentPost.imagePost;
    _cell.personStringPost.hidden = true;
    _cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
[self changeToCircle:_cell.profileImage];
_cell.profileImage.image = currentPost.profileImage;

[_cell.nameLabel setTitle:currentPost.nameString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_cell.eventLabel setTitle:currentPost.eventString forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[_cell.profileImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(profilePage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_cell.nameLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(profilePage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_cell.eventLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(eventPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_cell.likePage addTarget:self action:@selector(likePage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_cell.comment addTarget:self action:@selector(commentPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    _cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

return _cell;
```

}

Comment: Is "newPost" your unwind segue or the segue to the VC where you write the post?

Comment: newPost is the unwind segue

Comment: so, where is the call to `reloadData`?

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with the height / layout of the cell.  If adding it to the end makes it show up correctly, the labels in the cell might be displaying outside of the cell but it is not obvious because there is nothing underneath the cell.  Try adding some colors for the cells background so that you can see where the cell begins and ends, if you have content for that cell displaying outside of that area, you have the issue that I am talking about.

Comment: No its not that. When I add to the array, the new post is created at the top but I think the old picture that was being displayed in the second cell stays there, does not disappear, and then is also displayed in the third cell(where it should be). And then if I add a couple more post the picture is duplicated for some reason and appears at the bottom of the tableView.  The second person object [uiimage imageNamed@"iPhone.png"] is the image I am talking about

Comment: I think you need to post the code you have in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Also I tried it without the image and it works fine. So the problem lies with the image post being duplicated